# No newline after closing tag PHP

Tags: php, apache, tags, newline

In Example#1 of Instruction separation section of PHP Manual:

```
"
```

Example #1 Example showing the closing tag encompassing the trailing newline

```
< ? php echo "Some text"; ? >
```

No newline

```
< ?= "But newline now" ? >
```

The above example will output:

```
Some textNo newline

But newline now

"
```

What my page looks like:

```
Some text No newline But newline now
```

Thought the problem was here:

I've installed PHP 8.0.3 and in httpd.conf now works only:

```
LoadModule php_module         modules/libphp.so
```

Tried:

```
LoadModule php7_module         modules/libphp.so
LoadModule php8_module         modules/libphp.so
```

Result:
httpd: Syntax error on line 152 of /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf: Can't locate API module structure `php7_module' in file /usr/local/apache2/modules/libphp.so: /usr/local/apache2/modules/libphp.so: undefined symbol: php7_module

and same for php8.

Comment: Browsers don't render newlines in strings (unless in some elements like `<pre>` or `<textarea>`).

Comment: Thanks. Now I'll use nl2br.